# How do i share an sqlite memory database with another connection

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use a sqlite memory db ala `"file:zmem?mode=memory&cache=shared"` with multiple threads. To test this i have the following code which is not multi threaded, but just opens a second connection to the same memory db to read the results. Unfortunately i'm not able to find any working code samples on either sqlite.org or any other site on the internet.

I have the following C99 test code which works until another connection tries to access what the first connection created.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int exec(sqlite3 *db, char* sql) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int ret;
    do {
        ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);
        if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf("prep error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            break;
        }
        ret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (ret != SQLITE_DONE) {
            printf("step error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            break;
        }
        ret = SQLITE_OK;
    } while(0);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return ret;
}

sqlite3* getCon(char *name) {
    sqlite3 *db = 0;
    int flags = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE |
            SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_MEMORY | SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE;
    int ret = sqlite3_open_v2(name, &db, flags, 0);
    if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("no open");
    }
    return db;
}

void query(sqlite3 *db) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = 0;
    do {
        int ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM MyTable", -1, &stmt, 0);
        if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf("prep error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            break;
        }
        while ((ret = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *name = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
            printf("%s\n", name);
        }
        if (ret != SQLITE_DONE) {
            printf("step error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
    } while(0);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db = 0, *db2 = 0;
    char *label = "zmem";
    char bf[64];
    char *buf = &bf[0];
    int ret, i;
    do {
        db = getCon(label);
        if (!db) break;
        printf("connected\n");
        ret = exec(db, "CREATE TABLE MyTable (test VARCHAR(255));");
        if (ret != SQLITE_OK) break;

        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            sprintf(buf,"insert into MyTable (test) values('Hello Row %d')", i);
            ret = exec(db, buf);
            if (ret != SQLITE_OK) break;
        }
        query(db);

        db2 = getCon(label);
        if (!db2) break;

        printf("connected 2\n");
        query(db2);
    } while(0);

    if (db) sqlite3_close(db);
    if (db2) sqlite3_close(db2);
}
```

When i run this code it produces the following for me

```
connected
Hello Row 1
Hello Row 2
Hello Row 3
connected 2
prep error: no such table: MyTable
```

Could someone clue me in on how to properly do this?

Comment: According the [docs](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), in-memory databases do not support multiple connections. To share a connection to an in-memory database, you will have to pass the connection object around.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I meant the shared cache version of memory db. I'll update the question to be clearer about this.

Comment: You aren't using the `SQLITE_OPEN_URI` connection flag. Have you enabled URI filenames globally?

Comment: Have you enabled shared-cache mode? It is disabled by default.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I enabled `SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE` in the flags. I'm not using URIs because then the DB ends up in the file system and claims `MyTable` already exists on the second run.